# Sublime Text 2 - makeglossaries within build system

Tags: latex, customization, build-process, sublimetext2, glossaries

I need my build system run makeglossaries with "main" as the ONLY argument, but sublime always appends the current filename as final parameter. How can I prevent this?

The execution command looks like this (under command line):

```
$: makeglossaries main
```

My current `.sublime-build` file looks like this:

```
{
    // General settings; DO NOT MODIFY!!!
    "target": "make_pdf",
    "selector": "text.tex.latex",

    // Windows-specific settings
    // -------------------------
    "windows":
        {

            "cmd": ["texify", 
                    "-b", "-p",
                    "--tex-option=\"--synctex=1\""
            ],

            "cmd": ["makeglossaries",
                    "main"
            ],

            "cmd": ["texify", 
                    "-b", "-p",
                    "--tex-option=\"--synctex=1\""
            ],          

            "path": "",

            "file_regex": "^((?:.:)?[^:\n\r]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$"
        },

}
```

If you ask why I want to call `texify` twice, it's because `makeglossaries` needs to have a prebuild tex version on which it can inject the glossary. After injecting I want to get the final result.

Unfortunatelly, it does't work as I want. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're running on OSX/Linux, you can make a quick bash script that just ignores any additional arguments, and use that script as your `"cmd"`. Save the following in `~/bin` as `makeglossaries_main.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
/path/to/makeglossaries main
```

then change the relevant line in your build system to:

```json
"cmd": ["/home/adrian/bin/makeglossaries_main.sh"]
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: But how can I keep the feature I get from the original call of texify: `"cmd": ["texify", "-b", "-p", "--tex-option=\"--synctex=1\""]`. It enables jumping to the position which has been last modified in your tex document. Will it be kept even by using the script?

Comment: I'm not sure, since I don't know the full details of your build system. Feel free to update your question with the full contents of your `.sublime-build` file and I can take a look at it.

Comment: edited my question and extended it with the sublime-build file

Comment: does your build system still work when you make the changes I suggested?

Comment: I created my own Makefile which I called easily by `"cmd": ["make", "all"]`. This solved my problem. Anyway, thanks for your time and your advice.